# Why do I get the error "None of these files exist:", even though the file does exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo

I am trying to import something from ./components/task using this line of code:

```
import Task from './components/task';
```

but I get the error

```
None of these files exist:
  * components\task(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * components\task\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  1 | import React from 'react';
  2 | import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
> 3 | import Task from './components/task';
    |                   ^
  4 |
  5 | export default function App() {
  6 |   return (
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error. The screenshot clearly shows the path does exist.

This is the error I get, even though the path does exist.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWqxD.png

Answer (score 1):

from The Photo and code, I see nothing wrong but try to put ".js" after ./components/task.js just try it.

Or check that the task code is right or has export default

Comment: I wanted but it tell me to have at least 50 reputations to comment to the question